# Python to_excel underline selected rows

Tags: python

I have a question about formatting Python output:

my output looks like:

[image]

I want the output looks like this:

[image]

How to add underline and double underline to a dataframe? Thanks a lot.

I am trying to use this:
[image]

But does not work...

I also tried:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\2222222222.xlsx")

workbook = writer.book
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_underline()

fat_age_all.to_excel(writer, 'by Age',index = False, startrow=3, startcol=0)

worksheet.set_row(5, cell_format)

writer.save()
```

It does not work too. Please help thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24917201/13765033

Comment: I think you should check this related topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917201/applying-borders-to-a-cell-in-openpyxl