# Merge cells using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

In the process of a loop that Reads each workbook (I have like 4 separate excel files), and copy each column, cell by cell, to the new spreadsheet, **Could not get the formatting for the title which was merged cells and centered AND the line/cell borders**

```
                                #text formatting DATA
###############################Fomrat, Merge/Center/Bold Title, ceneter cells #########################

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelAutoNamed)
ws = wb['Validation']    #wb.active can also be used here

#auto size the cells 
for idx, col in enumerate(ws.columns, 1):
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(idx)].auto_size = True
 
# Merge the top cells for the title
# Make the fill red, and text white, bolt, size 16, and centred
ws.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=1, end_row=1, end_column=len(df.columns)+1)
cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=1)
cell.value = award
cell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="0091ea")
cell.font = Font(b=True, size=16, color="ffffff")
cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center")

# Centre all the cells excluding the title, column headers, and row indexes
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center")
```

I was missing two things in the combined Workbook,

**NUMBER 1**     - the title which was originally merged, centered, and over all of the columns corresponding to the
columns of the excel file IS NO longer merged, centered and over the columns

**NUMBER 2**  - the border lines are also no longer visible

**NUMBER 3**  - the headers are not auto.width

Before
[image: Before Combining Multiple Excel Files]       vs      [image: After Combining Multiple Excel Files] After

Here is code for the Bolded Borders

```
#borders every cell
hardworkbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Validation']
border_fmt = hardworkbook.add_format({'bottom':2, 'top':2, 'left':2, 'right':2})
worksheet.conditional_format(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, (len(df))+2, len(df.columns)), {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': border_fmt})
```

Comment: Call [merge_cells()](https://www.codespeedy.com/python-program-to-merge-excel-cell/#:~:text=Implementation%20Of%20Merging%20Cells%20using,()%20method%20for%20separating%20cells.), [alignment()](https://techoverflow.net/2021/09/24/how-center-text-horizontally-using-alignment-in-openpyxl/), [border()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917201/applying-borders-to-a-cell-in-openpyxl) and [Columns.autofit()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118823/16653700).

Comment: Can you please elaborate just a little more please @Alias Cartellano

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate #2 and #3. The cell borders and column widths are preserved from the original spreadsheets.

I was able to fix the merged cells by adjusting the min and max columns of the `MergedCellRange`. They need to be increased by the number of columns added to the sheet so far.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries, get_column_letter
from copy import copy
import os

# Tuple of filenames
filenames = ("filename1.xlsx", 
             "filename2.xlsx", 
             "filename3.xlsx", 
             "filename4.xlsx", 
            )

# Create a new workbook
new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
new_ws = new_wb.active

# column_num is the next column number to be written to in the new spreadsheet
column_num = 1

# Read each workbook, and copy each column, cell by cell, to the new spreadsheet
for filename in filenames:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.active
    
    # The min and max columns of every MergedCellRange needs to be shifted
    for range_ in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
        min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(range_.coord)
        min_col = get_column_letter(min_col + column_num - 1)
        max_col = get_column_letter(max_col + column_num - 1)
        new_ws.merged_cells.add(f"{min_col}{min_row}:{max_col}{max_row}")
    
    for column in ws.iter_cols():
        for cell in column:
            new_cell = new_ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=column_num, value=cell.value)  
            
            # Styles have to be manually copied
            if cell.has_style:
                new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
                new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
                new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
                new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
                new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
                new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
        
        # Preserve the same column width
        width = ws.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width
        new_column = new_ws.column_dimensions[new_cell.column_letter]
        new_column.width = width
        
        column_num += 1

# Save the new workbook to disk
new_filename = "combined.xlsx"
new_wb.save(new_filename)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(new_filename)
```