# openpyxl clearing borders in a for loop gives unexpected results

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with an Excel template that we are using to export data. When clearing the borders I seem to get inconsistent results. Some borders have the "no formatting" or "default" borders and in some cells the border is white.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUU2i.png)

Here is some relevant code:

```
    side_none = Side(border_style=None, color=None)
    side = Side(border_style="thin", color="FF000000")
    borders_none = Border(left=side_none, right=side_none, top=side_none, bottom=side_none)
    borders = Border(left=side, right=side, top=side, bottom=side)

    # Clear default border from template and apply new one to correct area
    apply_cell_borders(ws, "A2:J37", borders_none)  # This doesn't work correctly
    apply_cell_borders(ws, "A2:J" + str(row_cell - 1), borders)  # This seems to work fine
```

```
def apply_cell_borders(worksheet, cell_range, border_style):
    for row in worksheet[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            cell.border = border_style
```

I was expecting to get consistent results. The code that is used to apply the borders is slightly modified from this answer: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997375/22549796)

This seems like a bug, but I'm not sure if this is even the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using named styles instead:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, NamedStyle
from openpyxl.styles.borders import DEFAULT_BORDER
```

```
    side = Side(border_style="thin", color="FF000000")
        borders = Border(left=side, right=side, top=side, bottom=side)

        style_none = NamedStyle(name="none")
        style_none.border = DEFAULT_BORDER
        style_border = NamedStyle(name="border")
        style_border.border = borders

        # Clear default border and apply new one to correct area
        apply_cell_style(ws, "A2:J37", style_none)
        apply_cell_style(ws, "A2:J" + str(row_cell - 1), style_border)
```

```
    def apply_cell_style(worksheet, cell_range, named_style):
    for row in worksheet[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            cell.style = named_style
```